# erlang odbc datetime convertion

Tags: datetime, erlang, odbc

I try to describe my problem. When i make queries through Erlang odbc API:

> odbc:sql_query(Ref, "SELECT getdate()").
>
> ```
> {selected,[[]],[{{{2011,11,25},{8,46,27}}}]}
> ```

I read Erlang ODBC documentation and didn`t find proper odbc_data_type() for timestamp. After some dive into otp_src_R14B04/lib/odbc/c_src/odbcserver.c USER_TIMESTAMP has been discovered. I checked that when pass something like {sql_timestamp, [{{2011,11,2},{15,29,46}}]} to param_query/3 it works. : if make such query through native sql client, i will get little bit different data: "2011-11-25 09:02:44.053". Look at last 3 digits, it miss in data, which i got through Erlang. And my question is:

How i can tell Erlang do not try to convert datetime fields to sql_timestamp tuple OR how can i fix this without changing my query(without CAST to varchar inside query)?

P.S. I use mssql server 2008, but maybe it is common problem?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it, however you can use EXTRACT instead of CAST like this "SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM ts) FROM mytable" that will give you unix epoch timestamp with the precision you wanted.